# IPhone 6s Plus why an external camera like FLiR no longer charges the phone after interaction dialog?

Tags: iphone, charging, camera, ios

I got an external camera attachment for iPhone and it has an external power input. My understanding is that the camera is a part of an MFi (made for iPhone) - a certified accessory.

According to the manufacturer, it is supposed to charge phone when the camera receives external power:

1. I plug in the camera, the charging symbol appears
2. The **camera pops up a dialog** asking to interact with a default program
3. Charging symbol disappears and does not come back
4. I can confirm that the phone does not receive power - it discharges when the camera is attached.

I called the manufacturer and the camera is not defective - it has something to do with new iOS- I tried 9.0 and 9.2

**Is there something new about MFi (made for iPhone) program that prevents external devices from charging the phone?** Is there a way to prevent the phone from creating an interaction dialog for that particular app?

[image]

I verified that the accessory is MFi compatible:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure there's not any lint buildup in the Lightning port. Get a wooden or plastic toothpick (do *not* use anything metallic) and clean the port out, swiping from one edge to the other, then pulling out any bunched up lint or dust. Even a small amount of buildup will prevent the accessory from fully seating properly, sometimes generating a "This accessory is not supported" error, or simply preventing the device from charging, even when it has worked properly before.

Comment: Thanks, the port was indeed dirty, however, the issue appears on two different iPhones. I have updated my question with more info